# Upgrade Rails to latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to the Ruby on Rails environment and would like to get input in relation to upgrading my Rails environment from 4.0.2 to 4.2.3, which I assume is the latest version.

My Ruby version is `2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]`.

- Is upgrading a straight-forward process? If not, what is the upgrade path I need to follow?
- I normally use `bundle install cmd` to install all gems. Is there a similar command to upgrade to the latest version?
- Do I need to backup my apps before I try anything?

Comment: You should be using a version tracker such as git.

Comment: I would also highly recommend using rvm and [rvm gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics). They let you manage multiple versions of gems for various apps in order to avoid dependency conflicts.

Comment: @kjmagic - Can you please let me know what directories do include in git before upgrading? Should I just use the directory where ruby is installed ? I installed devkit while setting up this environment and use bundler to install gems.? Is bundler part of devkit and do i need to include that in git as weel before upgrade. ? I understand some of these questions might sound funny to you, but it'll definitely help in clearing confusion in my head!

Answer (score 2):

In your gemfile change:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
```

and in your terminal run `bundle update`.

If you are trying to update **ONLY** Rails, run: `bundle update rails`.

Comment: Before you do any of that, I suggest you thoroughly read the [Rails guides for upgrading](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). You can then upgrade from 4.0 to 4.1 and 4.1 to 4.2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. I've looked at rails upgrade guide mentioned by @mmichael and that tells me the differences between new and old versions. So do I need to update individual gems by following this guide or can I use the method provided by kjmagic13 to update rails.? Also, how do I upgrade my ruby version ?Please advise.

Comment: @pari, you can use `bundle update [gem name]` to update individual gems, including Rails itself, or `bundle update` to update all the gems in your list. I would recommend [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) for installing and managing multiple Ruby versions.